# My Samsung Series 5 (550P7C)

Tags: display, display-driver

My Samsung Series 5 (550P7C) only offers res. of: 1920 x 1080
I have purchased a new monitor with resolution of: 2560 x 1440
I cannot "boost" the resolution settings.....can anyone offer advice please?

Comment: But a new laptop or return your monitor and buy one compatible with your current laptop.

Comment: Go here and download the latest graphics driver and install it.....https://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/

Comment: More than likely your graphics chip cannot support that 2560x1440 resolution. I have a Dell monitor that is 2560x1600 and it needs a card that supports dual link dvi and a special dvi cable to get the max res.

Answer (score 0):

The
[Samsung Series 5 (550P7C)](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Samsung-Series-5-550P7C-S02DE-Notebook.75601.0.html)
has the graphical card of
[GeForce GT 650M](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-650m/specifications)
rated for a maximum resolution of `3840 x 2160`.

Asking it ti support two screens, one of `1920 x 1080` and the other of `2560 x 1440`,
would mean the support of a total screen area of `4480 x 2520`.

This very clearly exceeds the capabilities of the graphical card.

I can't see any possible solution, except upgrading the graphical card.
But this being a notebook, it is likely impossible to do.